# MacOS - Retrieving Sandbox App's Container folder in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, appstore-sandbox

From what I have read, this snippet:
`FileManager.default.urls(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)` is supposed to return the Application Support directory in the app's container folder.

However, in my project, it still prints as

> file:///Users/$user_name$/Library/Application%20Support/

The App has Sandbox enabled. Am I doing something wrong, or is there something bugged? I gladly provide more information, if you let me know which may be of interest here.

Edit: I just noticed under the "Release" configuration, it returns the expected path. Under "Debug", it does not - Is that expected / intentional?

Thanks in advance,
Sebastian

Comment: @Leo Dabus I am just trying to find the container folder of my sandboxed app, where I can save data. I don't necessarily need the Application Support folder. It is unrelated to the issue. The same issue applies with the documents directory. Instead of returning the apps documents folder path, it returns the user's, as if the app were not sandboxed.

Comment: *The same issue applies with the documents directory.* If so then your app is not sandboxed.

Comment: @vadian I just "solved" it - In the "Release" configuration, it returns the expected path. In "Debug", however, not. Is that intended?

Comment: Actually it should return the proper path regardless of the scheme

Comment: @vadian That is odd. I also believe it does not work when archived, but will try to confirm again. Any idea what could cause this oddness?

Answer (score 0):

For swift, just do :

```
let checkString = NSHomeDirectory()
```

In a sandboxed app, [NSHomeDirectory()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1413045-nshomedirectory?language=objc) returns the path to App Sandbox Container Directory, which is located at a system-defined path, within the user’s home directory.

This works regardless of scheme. Working for DEBUG too.